# Adjusting ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a layout that have been created mostly programmatically.Here is my xml and layout code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    tools:context="com.res_otomasyon.resotomasyon.SurveyScreen"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout">
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>


public void createSurvey(final String[] questionsAndPlaces) {

        final TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) activity.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        final String[] onlyQuestions = new String[questionsAndPlaces.length];
        final String[] onlyPlaces = new String[questionsAndPlaces.length];
        scrollView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) scrollView
                .getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = 100;
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 100);
        scrollView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        for (int i = 0; i < questionsAndPlaces.length; i++) {
            String[] questionAndPlacesSide = questionsAndPlaces[i].split("\\-");

            onlyQuestions[i] = questionAndPlacesSide[0];
            onlyPlaces[i] = questionAndPlacesSide[1];

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(activity);

            TableRow.LayoutParams layoutTableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
            tr.setLayoutParams(layoutTableRowParams);

            TableRow.LayoutParams layoutTextViewParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);

            layoutTextViewParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);

            TextView textQuestionView = new TextView(activity);
            textQuestionView.setTextAppearance(activity, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
            textQuestionView.setText((i + 1) + " - " + questionAndPlacesSide[0]);
            textQuestionView.setSingleLine(false);
            textQuestionView.setMaxLines(3);
            textQuestionView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER);
            textQuestionView.setLines(3);
            textQuestionView.setLayoutParams(layoutTextViewParams);
            tr.addView(textQuestionView);

            if (Integer.parseInt(questionAndPlacesSide[1]) < 16) // seçmeli soru rating bar ve text
            {
                TableRow.LayoutParams layoutRatingBarParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                layoutRatingBarParams.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);

                RatingBar ratingBarView = new RatingBar(activity);
                ratingBarView.setTag("" + questionAndPlacesSide[1]);
                ratingBarView.setNumStars(5);
                ratingBarView.setStepSize(1);
                ratingBarView.setRating(1);
                layoutRatingBarParams.gravity = (Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER);
                ratingBarView.setLayoutParams(layoutRatingBarParams);
                tr.addView(ratingBarView);
                tableLayout.addView(tr);
            } else // yazılı soru text ve cevap text
            {
                textQuestionView.setLines(1);
                tableLayout.addView(tr);

                TableRow.LayoutParams layoutEditTextParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
                layoutEditTextParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 0);

                EditText editText = new EditText(activity);
                editText.setSingleLine(false);
                editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
                editText.setMinLines(8);
                editText.setLines(8);
                editText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
                editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstyle);
                editText.setLayoutParams(layoutEditTextParams);
                editText.setTag("" + questionAndPlacesSide[1]);

                InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
                filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(500);
                editText.setFilters(filters);

                TableRow tr2 = new TableRow(activity);

                TableRow.LayoutParams layoutTableRowParams2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);

                tr2.setLayoutParams(layoutTableRowParams2);
                tr2.addView(editText);
                tableLayout.addView(tr2);
            }
        }

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(activity);

        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutTableRowParams2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);

        tr.setLayoutParams(layoutTableRowParams2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            TableRow.LayoutParams layoutEditTextParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
            layoutEditTextParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

            EditText editText = new EditText(activity);
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
            editText.setLayoutParams(layoutEditTextParams);

            if (i == 0)
                editText.setHint("Ad *");
            else
                editText.setHint("Soyad *");

            editText.setTag("" + (i + 20));

            InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
            filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(63);
            editText.setFilters(filters);
            tr.addView(editText);
        }
        tableLayout.addView(tr, layoutTableRowParams2);


        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutEditTextParams3 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
        layoutEditTextParams3.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 10);

        EditText editText3 = new EditText(activity);
        editText3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
        editText3.setLayoutParams(layoutEditTextParams3);

        editText3.setTag("" + 22);

        editText3.setHint("E-posta");

        InputFilter[] filters2 = new InputFilter[1];
        filters2[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(127);
        editText3.setFilters(filters2);

        EditText editText4 = new EditText(activity);
        editText4.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
        editText4.setLayoutParams(layoutEditTextParams3);
        editText4.setHint("Telefon");

        editText4.setTag("" + 23);

        InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
        filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(63);
        editText4.setFilters(filters);

        TableRow tr2 = new TableRow(activity);

        tr2.setLayoutParams(layoutTableRowParams2);
        tr2.addView(editText3);
        tr2.addView(editText4);
        tableLayout.addView(tr2);

        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutButtonParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layoutButtonParams.setMargins(200, 0, 200, 15);

        TableRow tr3 = new TableRow(activity);

        Button sendButton = new Button(activity);
        sendButton.setText("Anketi Tamamladım");
        sendButton.setLayoutParams(layoutButtonParams);
        sendButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstyle);
        sendButton.setHeight(80);

        tr3.setLayoutParams(layoutTableRowParams2);
        tr3.addView(sendButton);
        tableLayout.addView(tr3);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder surveyAnswers = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder surveyQuestions = new StringBuilder();

                EditText name = (EditText) tableLayout.findViewWithTag("20");
                EditText surname = (EditText) tableLayout.findViewWithTag("21");
                EditText email = (EditText) tableLayout.findViewWithTag("22");
                EditText phone = (EditText) tableLayout.findViewWithTag("23");


                userInfo.append(name.getText() + "*" + surname.getText() + "*" + email.getText() + "*" + phone.getText());

                for (int i = 0; i < onlyQuestions.length; i++) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(onlyPlaces[i]) < 16)
                        surveyAnswers.append(("*" + ((RatingBar) tableLayout.findViewWithTag(onlyPlaces[i])).getRating()).replace('.', ','));
                    else
                        surveyAnswers.append("*" + ((EditText) tableLayout.findViewWithTag(onlyPlaces[i])).getText());
                    surveyQuestions.append("*" + onlyQuestions[i]);
                }

                if (surveyAnswers.length() >= 1) {
                    surveyAnswers.deleteCharAt(0);
                }

                if (surveyQuestions.length() >= 1) {
                    surveyQuestions.deleteCharAt(0);
                }

                if (g.commonAsyncTask.client != null) {
                    g.commonAsyncTask.client.sendMessage("komut=anketCevaplari&kullaniciBilgileri=" + userInfo.toString() + "&cevapBilgileri=" + surveyAnswers.toString() + "&soruBilgileri=" + surveyQuestions.toString());
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder surveyMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                surveyMessage.setTitle("Anket Tamamlandı");
                surveyMessage.setMessage("Anketimize katıldığınız için teşekkür ederiz. Yeniden bekleriz..").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = surveyMessage.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is when the soft keyboard is on views in the bottom (buttons and textviews) stays behind the keyboard. I have searched too many articles about adjusting scrollview soft keyboard. Also I have tried to change `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" and all other options but when keyboard is on my layout looks like below.

[image: When keyboard on]
`

[image: When keyboard off]

I am really stuck on this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
in the activity decalration in manifest will adjust the layout resize option ...

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I have found what problem is. 
`        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

adjustResize not work in fullscreen..